# Formato JSON en Windows

Tags: nodejs, mongodb

Estoy creando un pequeño API con Node.js y MongoDB pero tengo una duda con la manera en que se ve la respuesta en JSON, ya que no se muestra en el formato normal como un objeto sino de forma lineal... como puedo corregir esto?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Los navegadores que reciben texto muestran... texto. Si quieres verlo de alguna otra manera, instálate una extensión que lo modifique (busca en la play store de chrome, hay multitud de extensiones para "embellecer" el formato JSON). Por cierto, el formato "normal" para un JSON es... exactamente el que se está mostrando! Un JSON fuera del código es texto, nada más.

Comment: Gracias pense que era algo que debia corregir en el codigo

Comment: Hay extensiones de google que mejoran el formato JSON, puedes encontrarlo en la Webstore de google, mira [éste enlace](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/json-viewer/gbmdgpbipfallnflgajpaliibnhdgobh?hl=es) o las extensiones relacionadas que encuentras más abajo.

Comment: Puedes mostrar la consulta que realizas y cómo la envías desde el backend al frontend? Hay formas de darle formato a la respuesta de tal manera que se vea como quieres en el navegador. Haz clic en [edit] y agrega lo que haga falta. Saludos